# :vsplit autocomplete not working with /django/ directory in VIM

Tags: vim, autocomplete, ctrlp

Normally if I type `:vsplit /path/to/some/directory`<kbd>Tab</kbd>, the available directories will autocomplete.

After doing a reinstall of VIM, there is one directory that now will not allow autocomplete, and I can't figure out why. The directory is `~/Sites/django/`. Once I type `~/Sites/`, <kbd>Tab</kbd> will show me `drupal` and `apps` directories, but will not show `django`. If my working directory is inside this django directory, `:vsplit` won't let me autocomplete either.

I did a `ls -haltr` on the directory and it looks the same as the others inside the `~/Sites/` directory.

Also, when I use the CtrlP plugin inside this directory, I get the error `"==NO ENTRIES=="`. In other places, CtrlP works fine.

Why might this be happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory is getting ignored because it has `/django/` in it's path...which was set by my Python linter. The linter causes Vim to ignore `/*django*/`. To see this, use `set wildignore` to see what directories are getting ignored.

I just changed the directory to `/dj/` and it works fine.

I could have also changed the wildignore directories by using `set wig-=my_directory` command.